# Добавить исключение try - catch?

Tags: java

Как создать исключение чтобы можно было только создавать матрицу до 4х4:

```
package matrix3x3;

/**
 *
 * @author Adil
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreateMatrix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows");

        int matrixRow = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Columns");

        int matrixCol = scan.nextInt();


        int[][] matrix = new int[matrixRow][matrixCol];

        enterMatrixData(scan, matrix, matrixRow, matrixCol);


        printMatrix(matrix, matrixRow, matrixCol);
  }
  public static void enterMatrixData(Scanner scan, int[][] matrix, int matrixRow, int matrixCol){
     System.out.println("Enter Matrix Data");

          for (int i = 0; i < matrixRow; i++)
          {
              for (int j = 0; j < matrixCol; j++)
              {
                  matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
              }
          }
  }

  public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix, int matrixRow, int matrixCol){
    System.out.println("Your Matrix is : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < matrixRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixCol; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+"\t");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Надо добавить исключение -- так добавьте. В чем вопрос-то, непонятно.

Comment: можете помочь я не могу додуматься как его добавить. Все испробовал ошибку выдает

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы смысл был ясен из него самого, а не из комментариев.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Application {

    private int[][] matrix;

    public Application(int row, int column) {
        if (row > 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The row of matrix can not be grater than 4: row - " + row);
        }
        if (column > 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The column of matrix can not be grater than 4: column - " + column);
        }
        matrix = new int[row][column];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows");
        int matrixRow = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Columns");
        int matrixCol = scan.nextInt();

        Application application = new Application(matrixRow, matrixCol);
        application.enterMatrixData(scan);
        application.printMatrix();
    }

    public void enterMatrixData(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter Matrix Data");

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    public void printMatrix() {
        System.out.println("Your Matrix is : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

В той конструкции, которая реализована у вас (ввод данных в методе `main()`), проще проверять ввод без всяких исключений, например, как-то так:

```
    System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows");
    int matrixRow = scan.nextInt();
    if (matrixRow < 1 || matrixRow > maxSize)
      showErrorAndExit();         // Вывести сообщение об ошибке и завершить работу

    System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Columns");
    int matrixCol = scan.nextInt();
    if (matrixCol < 1 || matrixCol > maxSize)
      showErrorAndExit();         // Вывести сообщение об ошибке и завершить работу

    // Данные допустимы -- продолжить работу
    int[][] matrix = new int[matrixRow][matrixCol];
    ....
```

Но если размеры матрицы вводятся в отдельном методе, то в нем можно проверять эти значения и в случае их выхода за допустимые границы генерировать исключение, а в методе, который управляет ходом процесса в целом, ловить и обрабатывать это исключение. Например, как-то так:

```
  static int[][] matrix = null;
  static int numOfRows; numOfCols;
  static final int maxSize = 4; 

  public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
      getMatrixSize();        // может вызвать исключение
      printMatrix(enterMatrixData(numOfRows; numOfCols)); // в случае исключения это не выполнится
    } catch (Exception x) {   //  поймали исключение 
      System.out.println(x.getMessage()); // выведем сообщение
    }
  }

  private static getMatrixSize() throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows");
    numOfRows = scan.nextInt();
    if (numOfRows < 1 || numOfRows > maxSize) // недопустимый размер
      throw new Exception("Недопустимое число строк: " + numOfRows);

    System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Columns");
    numOfCols = scan.nextInt();
    if (numOfCols < 1 || numOfCols > maxSize) // недопустимый размер
      throw new Exception("Недопустимое число столбцов: " + numOfCols);
  }
```

Comment: Мне это не интересно, вам это не полезно, и здесь это не приветствуется. Учитесь сами и пишите сами.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать проверку вводимого числа размеров матрицы по типу

```
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Введите число");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Это не число!");
        sc.next();
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
} while (number <= 0 || number > 4);
System.out.println("Вы ввели: " + number);
```

Answer (score -4):

Просто так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter The Number Of Matrix Rows");

        int matrixRow = isNUmberEqual4(scan.nextInt());



public int isNUmberEqual4(int number) {
 if(  number > 4) {
            System.out.println("так нельзя");
            return;
    //или кинуть ошибку, но тоже особо не надо
    //вообщем простая проверка нужна 
        }
}
```

Comment: А если пользователь введет 5?

Comment: @notaProgrammer, не понял за что диз 
я показал пример,в котором можно доработать  что-то или нет.
Если введет 5 ничего не произойдет.

А , я прочитал задание как только матрицу 4 на 4.
Но смысл не меняется, по идеи метод при первом некорректном вводе должен завершиться.

Comment: автор четко указал, что можно создавать матрицу до  4х4, то есть больше нельзя. Выходит условие должно быть `if (n > 4)`. Но некак не `if (n != 4)`. Зачем на такой простой вопрос давать неверный ответ?

Comment: Ты понимашь, что означает "до"? Это значит 3х3 можно, 5х5 - нельзя. А у тебя все наоборот...

Comment: @notaProgrammer, то есть ты не понял почему я удалил комментарий ? 
Я не понимаю, ты приходишь обсуждать или доказать себе что-то? 

Окей, тогда выведи сюда кусок из jdk с array где висит проверка на -1